# Switch between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to do the following. There are two fragments first and second. Necessary make the transition between them. When I go from first fragment in the second, first stored in the stack. When I click the Back button the second fragment is removed and returned first fragment from the stack. Again I can not go in the second fragment - it has been deleted. How can I solve this problem?

In main activity (callback for Fragment1):

```
@Override
public void onNavigate() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment1 newFragment1 = (Fragment1) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag_1");
    Fragment2 newFragment2 = (Fragment2) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag_2");
    ft.replace(R.id.main, newFragment2);
    ft.remove(newFragment1);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Fragments I added dynamically:

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.main, new Fragment1(), "frag_1");
    ft.add(R.id.main, new Fragment2(), "frag_2");
    ft.commit();
```

Comment: Why do you call ft.remove(newFragment1); if you already have replaced it and by this was removed already?

Comment: Just in case :) But the problem is the destruction Fragment 2 when pressing key Back.

Comment: And you want to access the Fragment2 object after the back button was clicked?

Comment: I solved this problem :). I hide first fragment and add transaction to the back stack. When I click button Back I return to fragment 1.
[code]
 @Override
 public void onNavigate() {
  FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  Fragment1 newFragment1 = (Fragment1) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag_1");
  ft.hide(newFragment1);
  ft.addToBackStack(null);
  ft.commit();
 }[code]

Comment: You should put your solution in an Answer. Solutions in comments often go unnoticed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem :). I hide first fragment and add transaction to the back stack. When I click button Back I return to fragment

```
@Override 
public void onNavigate() { 
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
    Fragment1 newFragment1 = (Fragment1) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag_1"); 
    ft.hide(newFragment1); 
    ft.addToBackStack(null); 
    ft.commit(); 
}
```