# How to alternate between 2 layouts in the same activity?

Tags: android, layout

I want to know how to get the same activity to show 2 layouts. I explain, I have an activity with a login, and within this same are 2 buttons (one called "login" and another "SingUp") the idea is that when you click on one of these 2 shows a different layout for each button, but without having to change all activity in one. I achieved it partially by adding the SetContentView to the Onclic of each button, and it works but only the first time, without the activity it starts with the login layout and then I click on the singUp button, if it changes layout but if later I want to return to the login layout I can not anymore I have to restart the app.What I want to achieve is to change layout in the same activity using buttons, whatever method they mention or they help me to know which part of my code is wrong :(Thank you.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button btnLogin,btnSignup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnSignup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignup);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    });

    btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        }
    });




}
```

}
with the previous code and managed to alternate between 2 layouts in the same activity, but the buttons only work the first time if I try to go to a layout by pressing a button for the second time, this simply does not work until I restart the app.

Comment: In your case the appropriate approach would be using two fragments in your activity.

Comment: Use two fragments, always recommended for this type of situation, this way you can keep network calls, views etc separate for both the flows.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
Try recreating the Activity. Save which view to load then recreate.

```
private Button btnLogin,btnSignup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(preference.getInt(ACTIVITY)==1)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    else 
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    btnLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnSignup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignup);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            preference.setInt(ACTIVITY, 1);
            recreate();
        }
    });

    btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            preference.setInt(ACTIVITY, 2);
            recreate();
        }
    });

}
```

**Option 2**

Use fragments. Create 2 fragments and inflate them into activity on onclick of button

**Option 3**

Use VISIBLE/GONE with predefined layouts inside activity_main

Answer (score 0):

Create one layout with two separate views that `match_parent`'s height and width.

Hide / show each one when switching views

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/parent"
  android:width="match_parent"
  android:height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visibile">
    <!-- Add child views here -->
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/sign_up"
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <!-- Add child views here -->
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then programmatically...

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mainView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loginView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});

btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mainView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        loginView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

You can approach it in other ways using Fragments, which one could argue that's the more appropriate way.
[Switch between two fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079150/switch-between-two-fragments)